# Stretching path based on character positions in text element

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm writing a document in HTML5 with included SVG (actually ePub3), and I wanted to have a path in the SVG going from one character position in a text element to another.  I found a way to do it, but it seems like a particularly awkward way, and I am wondering if anyone has any tips for improving it.

A bit more context:  the particular illustration is to demonstrate how multiplication by integer powers of 10 shifts the decimal point around in decimal representations of numbers (particularly for converting between percentages and decimal representations, multiplying or dividing by 100).  So I want the decimal number in a text element, and an arrow (specified as a path element with an arrowhead marker on one end) under it showing the shift of the decimal point from one position to another.  But I want to do in in a general enough way that the arrow stretches for me if I need to change the font size or add digits between the start and stop positions of the arrow.

Here is what I came up with:

```html
<svg id="shift"  height="40" width="85">
<defs> 
<marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" refX="3" refY="0" > 
<path d="M 0 6 L 3 0 6 6" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0" rotate="90"/></marker>
</defs>
<text id="fullstring" x="0" y="15" fill="black" font-family="serif" font-size="100%">10<!--
--><tspan id="firstdec" fill="blue">.</tspan>0000<tspan id="seconddec" fill="red">.</tspan>00</text>
<path id="decarrow" stroke="black" fill="white" stroke-width="1" d=""
style="marker-end: url(#arrowhead);"/>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
var arrowpath = document.getElementById("decarrow");
var firstdecbox = document.getElementById("firstdec").getExtentOfChar(0);
document.getElementById("fullstring").setAttribute("y",""+firstdecbox.height);
document.getElementById("shift").setAttribute("height",""+(1.4*firstdecbox.height+15));
document.getElementById("shift").setAttribute("width", ""+document.getElementById("fullstring").getComputedTextLength());
var seconddecbox = document.getElementById("seconddec").getExtentOfChar(0);
var startx = firstdecbox.x+firstdecbox.width/2;
var starty = firstdecbox.y+firstdecbox.height;
var stopx = seconddecbox.x+seconddecbox.width/2;
var stopy = seconddecbox.y+seconddecbox.height;
var bendheight = 15;
arrowpath.setAttribute("d", "M "+startx+" "+starty+" L "+ startx+" "+(starty+bendheight)+" "+stopx+" "+(stopy+bendheight)+" "+stopx+" "+stopy);
]]></script>
</svg>
```

I can't help thinking that there must be a better way to do this.  What I really want is a way to specify a path with starting point and ending point based on character positions in a text element.  Is there such a way to specify path data relative to character positions?  Or have I really stumbled my way onto the best available option?